# python: load thrift classes and run interactive shell

Tags: python, console, thrift, python-interactive

In django framework you may run

```
./manage.py shell
```

and you'll be inside interactive shell with django settings. I can run a python interactive console using

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import code

code.interact(local=locals())
```

I want to do the same as django does - execute python script to get inside the interactive shell (with my local thrift packages already imported - that's the clue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you mean by "with my local thrift packages already imported", but if you want to start an interactive shell with a specific set of symbols already defined in the global namespace, I'd do it in a function, and `import` the symbols in there, to avoid polluting the sub-shell with any unwanted symbols from the rest of your code.

For example, if you wanted to start an interactive shell with `sys` and `os` already imported, then something like this ought to work...

```
>>> import code
>>> def start_shell():
...     import sys, os
...     code.interact(local=locals())
...
>>> start_shell()
Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:28:01)
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', 'os', 'sys']
```

...noting that `sys` and `os` are defined, but not `code` because it was imported into the global namespace, not the local one.